# System Call Error (Expected ")" before struct)

Tags: kernel, system-calls

I am trying to write a system call to get the current time. However, I keep getting expected ) before struct.

My system call definition is

SYSCALL_DEFINE1(current_xtime,struct timespec *, current_time)

This line gives the error. I am using linux kernel version 3.8.8. What could cause it?

Comment: Have you tried running just the preprocessor phase and seeing what the code looks like?